# Is there a way to not show unwanted text in a long varchar in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT ID, Time, IF(Media=1, 'Yes', 'No') AS Media, Text FROM Database.data;
```

The Text is a `varchar(2000)` and i would like to take out some specified text from it.
This doesnt seems to work

```
SUBSTRING ("*******" FROM Text FOR 6)
```

Is it possible to get the text below returned somehow,
i dont know the place for the text so LEFT and RIGHT doesnt seem to work here, maybe its possible to use the `*****` as a starting point somehow, that text is always there and is the only thing near the information i want.

Its ok to if the output comes in 2 columns

Example:

```
This
is garbage text

More garbage
I want this information.
*******This text is always 6char.
More garbage here.
and here
```

Comment: Please edit your question and rephrase it by showing us clear input and the expected output.

Comment: Use `LOCATE()` to get the position of `*******`, then use that in `SUBSTR()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LOCATE()`

```
SUBSTR(Text, LOCATE(Text, '*******')+7, 6)
```